# "Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly” when trying to start service MySQL56 on Win7 x64

Tags: windows-7-x64, mysql-5.6

I'm using MySQL 5.6 as my database. It was working fine for a couple of days. Now I see that the "MySQL56" service hasn't started, and I tried to start it manually,but  it says "Windows could not start MySQL Service on Local Computer. Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.". I checked the log file provided by MySQL, it says that

```
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-25 10:30:14 bd4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 369.0M
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 250758982
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-03-25 10:30:14 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-03-25 10:30:15 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-03-25 10:30:15 2536 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 250758992
2015-03-25 10:30:16 2536 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-03-25 10:30:16 2536 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-25 10:30:16 b80  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 2944 in file trx0purge.cc line 699
InnoDB: Failing assertion: purge_sys->iter.trx_no <= purge_sys->rseg->last_trx_no
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2015-03-25 10:30:16 2536 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.20 started; log sequence number 250758992
2015-03-25 10:30:16 2536 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-03-25 10:30:16 2536 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-03-25 10:30:16 2536 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-03-25 10:30:16 2536 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-03-25 10:30:16 2536 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 1 event
2015-03-25 10:30:16 2536 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.20'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-03-25 10:30:16 2536 [Note] Event Scheduler: scheduler thread started with id 1
```

Can anyone help me to identify and solve my problem?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try to follow these steps and check:

1. First try to stop the MySQL service.
2. In the next step please try to open mysql path\data
3. Then delete both ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1.
4. And finally restart the service

Also check [Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly” when trying to install MySQL on Win7 x64](https://serverfault.com/questions/214435/error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpectedly-when-trying-to-install-mysql-o)